# Android GPS - location tracking periodically

Tags: android, gps

all
I'm working on my Android app which is required to track location of android periodically. The result will be sent to my server(maybe in php) whenever I click button "Get Location" on the server or sent periodically if I click button "Track Location", I have searched much for this topic but it seem to me that they are not helpful for me.
Can anyone give me a detail solution with full code?
Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: I wish someone would do my job with a detailed solution and full code!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get track location right after click Get Location on the server, you have to implement an API to check if need to upload location, then create a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on client with calling this API, then upload when needed. And for Track location by period, you could also use service for it. For details, please try to search by yourself, there are many solutions for them already.

P/S: noone will give you a detail solution with full code, it's your job, not us!